# Creating executable for windows using Qt program in Linux

Tags: windows, linux, eclipse, qt

I have developed a small Qt project with Qt Eclipse integration on linux and I would like to make a windows executable file (.exe) for the same project. So, my app could run on both systems.
Will my Qt with Eclipse as plugin help me to generate `.exe` in Linux ?

Please tell me what is the procedure to get .exe from Linux and what has to be installed?

Answer (score 4):

You have to cross-compile.

http://divided-mind.blogspot.com/2007/09/cross-compiling-qt4win-on-linux.html

http://silmor.de/29

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you pls guide me which cross-compiler to be installed in linux and i also already have GCC compiler in my linux machine. Should that be replaced by GCC cross-compiler. Is GCC compiler and cross-compiler are same or we get it in different packages??

Comment: I am not sure as I have not done it yet. If you can give me a day or two, I will try and report back. Right now, I am at my friends' place.

Comment: Can i install MinWG Cross comipler on Linux or is it for only widows because i haven't found any information abt it.
If its not pls do suggest me a cross compiler to be installed on Linux.